# EC2 SSH Bash Profile

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, terminal, profile

I've set up an Ubuntu image on EC2 and everything is working great. However, when I SSH onto the server my terminal prompt is always `$` and several features I'm used to in the default Ubuntu terminal (tab auto-complete, for example) are not available. I've tried adding a `.bashrc` file to my home directory but that didn't help. How can I set this up?

Cheers,

Pete

Comment: What shell `echo $SHELL`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your shell is not bash(`echo $SHELL`, show dash or other), change login shell to bash.
First, run bash to check it:

```
/bin/bash
```

If bash work, change login shell(change LOGIN):

```
usermod -s /bin/bash LOGIN
```

Comment: I hope you can help, as I have this same problem.  If I ssh in with my secondary account (call it john), bash does not load.  However, I have run usermod -s /bin/bash john from a su account, and also have run chsh /bin/bash from the john ssh account.  When I look at the /etc/passwd it returns `john:x:1001:1001::/home/john:/bin/bash`.  And when I ssh into the account, and type /bin/bash, it loads bash.  However, for some reason, bash will not load automatically and I stuck with sh as the login shell.  Any advice?